# warning message when running specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

I have the following:

```
  def toggle_follow_user tmp_id
    user=User.find(tmp_id)
```

but when I run specs I get the following warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: You are passing an instance of ActiveRecord::Base to `find`. Please pass the id of the object by calling `.id`.
```

what is it trying to tell me and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Just for the sake of a test...  I'm not sure what you are passing in that gets assigned to the tmp_id parameter, but I would surmise its an active record object, can you try this?

```
def toggle_follow_user tmp_id
  user=User.find(tmp_id.id)
end
```

If that works, its because whatever you were sending into `toggle_follow_user` was an entire active record "row" where Find wants an integer now (representing the ID... it used to pull it out natively, but that is going away it seems)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `toggle_follow_user(a_user)`, not `toggle_follow_user(a_users_id)`. Try this:

```
def toggle_follow_user(user)
  # just delete the line where you ::find the user, you're already passing it in
```

This will fix this particular issue - but check that it doesn't break anything else in your code!

If you *are* wanting to pass the user's `id` and `find` it inside the method, then look a call or two down your stack trace, because it's the whole object that's being passed in.